# Custom Servlet Filter not getting applied to all resources

Tags: filter, servlet-filters, tomcat9

I have created a simple Filter class that adds some response headers to all the resources requested.
I have created a jar file and added the same to tomcat lib folder. Also the filter is added to the web.xml for url mapping /*

When I request the page of my application I can see filter is been invoked as the sysout statements are printed correctly but the headers are getting added to some of the assets only. 
I am pretty confused as to why it is getting added to only some assets and not to all.

Filter class as below

```
package com.headers.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class MySecurityHeadersFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
} 

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
throws IOException, ServletException {

chain.doFilter(request, response);

HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

httpResp.addHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';base-uri 'self';form-action 'self';");
httpResp.addHeader("Expect-CT", "max-age=86400, enforce, report-uri=https://"+ httpReq.getHeader("host").trim() +"/bham/user/reportCT");
httpResp.addHeader("Feature-Policy", "vibrate 'none'; geolocation 'none';");
httpResp.addHeader("Referrer-Policy", "no-referrer-when-downgrade");

System.out.println("Response Headers: "+((HttpServletResponse) response).getHeaderNames());
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
}

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.headers.config</groupId>
<artifactId>MySecurityHeadersFilter</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>MySecurityHeadersFilter Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>MySecurityHeadersFilter</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I am using tomcat 9 and have added below filter mapping in web.xml. This is the only filter added

```
<filter>
<filter-name>MySecurityHeadersFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.cdp.headers.config.MySecurityHeadersFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>MySecurityHeadersFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>MySecurityHeadersFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
<filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
<async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
<filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>ExpiresByType text/css</param-name>
<param-value>access plus 10 minutes</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>ExpiresByType application/javascript</param-name>
<param-value>access plus 10 minutes</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

WHen I execute the URL this is what I can see in the catalina logs. The headers that I have added are not present.

```
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
Response Headers: [Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection, Accept-Ranges, ETag, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Expires, Content-Type, Content-Length, Date, Keep-Alive, Connection, Server]
```

Comment: Source code of the filter please

Comment: @MarkThomas I have added the filter code and the pom.xml. Also how do I use request.getHeaderNames method? If i try to use it in my current class it gives error saying method doesn't exist. DO i need to change version of servlet api or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set headers once the response is committed.

The reason your filter works for some requests and not others is that some requests commit the response before your filter can add the headers and some do not.

If you move the `chain.doFilter(request, response);` call to after the code where you set the headers the Filter should apply to everything.

If you want to ensure that the subsequent requests don't change the headers, you have several options. Committing the response is the simplest but it is rather a blunt instrument and may break some of the downstream requests (e.g. any that try to do a `RequestDispatcher.forward()`. A better solution is to wrap the response and intercept all the header altering calls and filter out the ones you don't want.

Comment: Hello Mark, I have tried moving the chain.doFilter(request, response); as the last line of the method but that didn't help either. When you say wrapping the response is there an example?

Comment: Have created a HttpServletResponseWrapper and it is now working

Answer (score 0):

The Response wrapper class that worked is as below for anyone that might face the same issue

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HeaderResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
private CharArrayWriter writer;

public HeaderResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
    super(response);
    writer = new CharArrayWriter();
}
}
```

The doFilter method will change too

```
HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

HeaderResponseWrapper headerResponseWrapper = new HeaderResponseWrapper(httpResp);

headerResponseWrapper.addHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'");
chain.doFilter(request, headerResponseWrapper);
```

Answer (score -1):

Makes no sense to me, filter applies to everything, chances are the request is not really getting to the server, do you see a call being made in the browser developer toolbar? does it return 200?.

Comment: Yes I can see call been made to the filter as visible from the catalina.out logs as well as can see the call in developers tool.

Comment: May it be that you have other filters? are you using spring or something like that?

Comment: But that shouldn't cause it to be added to some assets and not to others. Like 1.js has got the headers but 2.js hasn't which is what i am not able to understand. They both belong to same path

Comment: Javascript is usually cached in the browser, if you want to make sure a request is made to the server put a new Date() in the resource request in the JSP.

Comment: I have cleared the cache too in my browser for each request but still the same issue on the fresh requests.

Comment: With the info I have no idea I am afraid sorry pal, good luck

Comment: Thanks Raul for tyour time :)